# Dynamically adding component when it's resources is loaded

Tags: angular

I want to add a component as a child of a another component dynamically but when the image inside the child component is loaded.

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

child.component.html

```
<div>
   <img src="example.com/image.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue description is not very clear (or rather makes no sense). You have a `parent` component, which needs to dynamically `add` a `child` component into it's `DOM` but only when the child's component's image has been loaded?

Comment: @tftd Exactly what I want.

Comment: You could do `ajax` requests to the collection of images from the `parent` component and then you can use the [`Dynamic Component Loader`](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) to load the component dynamically. You can also use `*ngFor` in the `parent` component which adds `<child [url]=...>` and in the `child` you'd show a progress bar while the image is loading. You'd again have to use `ajax` request at `ngOnInit`, but at least the user sees what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **directive** like this:

```
import {AfterContentChecked, Directive, ElementRef, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appIfOnDom]'
})

export class AppIfOnDomDirective implements AfterContentChecked {
    isCreated: boolean;

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {this.isCreated = false}

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        if (document.body.contains(this._elementRef.nativeElement) && !this.isCreated) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
            }, 300);
            this.isCreated = true;
        } else if (this.isCreated && !document.body.contains(this._elementRef.nativeElement)) {
            this._viewContainerRef.clear();
            this.isCreated = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and use ***appIfOnDom** in html, like this:

```
<div *appIfOnDom>
    <img src="example.com/image.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add to whole component when it's loaded not just the template, and i want that to be programmatically through the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngAfterViewInit` of angular to make sure the view is loaded or you can use `onload` of `img` tag to see if the image is loaded

Comment: I want to add to whole component when it's loaded not just the template, and i want that to be programmatically through the parent component.